# White spaces in Density plots

Tags: plotting

I have the following function that is dependent on three parameters ω, κ2, and x:

```
f[ω_, κ2_, 
x_] := (384000.` x κ2 Sqrt[κ2^2])/(1600000000 x^2 \
κ2^2 (1/100000000 + 4 ω^2) + (κ2^2 + 
4 ω^2) (16 + 
8 (1/10000 - 4 ω^2) + (1/100000000 + 
   4 ω^2) (1 + 4 ω^2)) + 
80000 x κ2 ((κ2 - 4 ω^2) (1/100000000 + 
   4 ω^2) + 
4 (κ2/10000 + 4 ω^2))) + (9.6` (κ2^2 + 
4 ω^2))/(1600000000 x^2 κ2^2 (1/100000000 + 
4 ω^2) + (κ2^2 + 4 ω^2) (16 + 
8 (1/10000 - 4 ω^2) + (1/100000000 + 
   4 ω^2) (1 + 4 ω^2)) + 
80000 x κ2 ((κ2 - 4 ω^2) (1/100000000 + 
   4 ω^2) + 
4 (κ2/10000 + 
   4 ω^2))) + (0.0122` (1600000000 x^2 κ2^2 + 
80000 x κ2 (κ2 - 4 ω^2) + (1 + 
  4 ω^2) (κ2^2 + 
  4 ω^2)))/(1600000000 x^2 κ2^2 (1/100000000 + 
4 ω^2) + (κ2^2 + 4 ω^2) (16 + 
8 (1/10000 - 4 ω^2) + (1/100000000 + 
   4 ω^2) (1 + 4 ω^2)) + 
80000 x κ2 ((κ2 - 4 ω^2) (1/100000000 + 
   4 ω^2) + 4 (κ2/10000 + 4 ω^2)))
```

I intend to plot a density plot such that the x-axis takes on κ2, the y-axis takes on x, and the z-axis gives the **difference in the maxima of the function at each κ2 and x value as a function of ω**. I proceed to construct a double loop like so:

```
ωarr = 
Table[{i, j, 
Max[ω /. 
   NSolve[(D[f[ω, i, j], ω]) == 0 && 
     D[f[ω, i, j], {ω, 2}] < 0, Reals]] - 
 Min[ω /. 
   NSolve[(D[f[ω, i, j], ω]) == 0 && 
     D[f[ω, i, j], {ω, 2}] < 0, Reals]]}, {i, 0, 
100, 1}, {j, 0, 10^-3, 10^-5}];
```

and then proceeding to plot:

```
ListDensityPlot[Flatten[ωarr,1], PlotRange->All, PlotRangeClipping -> False]
```

What I get is some density plot with mostly blue gradient. My problem is of the white spaces that shows up: Should the maxima difference be 0, wouldn't that be represented by a blue colored gradient rather than empty white spaces? What is the problem here?

[image]

I could use any help that I can get. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am puzzled why the plot looks like that..as a workaround, since your data is on a regular grid you can use the array form of `ListDensityPlot` :

```
ListDensityPlot[Transpose[Map[#[[3]] &, \[Omega]arr, {2}]],
  DataRange ->   MinMax /@ Transpose[Flatten[\[Omega]arr, 1][[All, {1, 2}]]]]
```

[image]

Comment: I copied and pasted exactly what you wrote and came up with a much better plot, albeit different from yours: https://imgur.com/o0PhcUy

As you can see, my yellow contour has these tiny ladders at the edge whereas yours doesn't. Can you explain the discrepancy in this? what should be a better solution ?

Comment: i think i made the increment `10^-4` to speed it up.